# how can I include php in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Let's say I have some html file like this:

```
<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
```

Given that I have referenced jQuery correctly, and I have a .js file like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').html(4);
});
```

That will output 4 when the html is viewed in a browser. Why does it not show anything when I do this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').html(<?php echo 4; ?>);
 });
```

Comment: Aren't you missing some quotes? `$('div').html("<?php echo 5; ?>");`

Comment: ah...I missed that was a separate .js file. As Marcus says, it's likely not getting executed by the PHP engine. Tell your PHP engine and/or server to also parse .js files.

Comment: You can set the content type of the file to let the client know its a js file

Comment: Why are you setting the content of the DIV on page-load via JavaScript when you can do it on the server via PHP?

Comment: @Sime, I am working on something that needs to be executed using jQuery. this is a picture of what I am trying to achieve. thanks though

Answer (score 6):

Well a .js file isn't a PHP file. You can alternatively rename your .js file into `blah.js.php` where you can execute blocks of PHP inside that file, but still have the file act like jQuery when you include it in your page.

Comment: you should also be able to tell the server/php to parse .js files as well.

Comment: That would work too, but I think it's safe to assume Ronny isn't familiar with MIME types.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep the dynamic content on the page and leave the Javascript file static. This will allow the browser to cache your Javascript. So, here is how you can get your dynamic values to your static Javascript.

Your page should look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div></div>
    <script>
        var myNumber = <?php echo 4; ?>;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And your Javascript file should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").html(myNumber);
});
```